What is the universal/fine uniformity on a topological group?
Cross posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889335
I'm aware that every topological group is uniformizable: given a neighborhood $U\in\mathcal N(e)$ of the identity, the set $D_U=\{\langle x,y\rangle:x^{-1}y\in U\text{ and }xy^{-1}\in U\}$ is an entourage of the diagonal and $\mathbb D=\{D_U:U\in\mathcal N(e)\}$ is a base for (one example of) a uniformity compatible with the topology.
Is this $\mathbb D$ a base for the universal/fine uniformity (the union of all compatible uniformities) on a topological group? If not, when is it? (Of course, compactness is sufficient, as there is a unique compatible uniformity in that scenario.) And if not, is there a similar algebraic characterization of the universal/fine uniformity?

This is a very long comment that I initially typed as a (now deleted) answer which might still be useful. Your $\mathbb D$ is a basis for the two-sided uniformity, so you're asking when the two-sided uniformity on a topological group $G$ agrees with the finest one. If this is the case, then in particular every continuous function $G\to\mathbb R$ must be two-sided uniformly continuous. Now this is very close to what is known as property U, which is the statement that every continuous function $G\to\mathbb R$ is left- (equivalently right-) uniformly continuous.

For a topological group $G$ which is not a P-spaces, having property U is equivalent to being pseudocompact (Comfort-Ross, Pseudocompactness and uniform continuity in topological groups, Theorem 1.5+Theorem 3.1). Among P-spaces pseudocompactness is not required as discrete groups show (they also show that pseudocompactness is not required for the two-sided and the finest uniformities to agree). There are also examples of groups which are nondiscrete, not pseudocompact, but have property U (hence they are P-spaces), see Theorem 3.2 of the same paper

However it is not immediately clear to me whether the statement "every continuous real valued function on $G$ is two-sided uniformly continuous" implies that $G$ has property U.

At least on the (additive) reals it is not because the group uniformity ($\mathbb{R}$ is Abelian so they are all the same) is the metric uniformity. And uniformly continuous with respect to that unifority is, well, uniformly continuous.
On the other hand every continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$-with-the-fine-uniformity to $\mathbb{R}$-with-the-normal-topology is uniformly continuous when the codomain carries the metric uniformity.

More generally by my comments above in no Abelian group (more generally in no balanced group) the two-sided uniformity agrees with the finest one
